# Element query: find entries where a field's value is greater than, or less than another field's value?

Tags: entries, craft3, field, elementquery

I would like to do something like this:

```
craft.entries.section('mySection').field1('> field2').all()
```

And it should return all the entries in `mySection` whose `field1` value is greater than their `field2` value.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that any solution where you run a query and then conditionally render the result isn't very efficient.

You can do this in SQL by using the `where()` condition.

```
craft.entries
    .section('mySection')
    .where('content.field_field1 > content.field_field2')
    .all()
```

Documentation on the `where()` condition can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail).

Comment: Is the syntax for the `.where()` clause in your example documented anywhere? Especially the `content` table and and `field_` prefix for custom fields. I can only find the [Yii framework documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail), but of course that doesn't tell you anything about Craft's database structure, and [Craft's own documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#advanced-element-queries) is sorely lacking regarding those advanced queries ...

Comment: I don't believe it is documented by Craft no, their `where()` condition [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#conditions) links straight through to Yii, as that's where `where()` is implemented. Usually I reverse engineer this sort of thing using the `getRawSql()` [function](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/element-queries.html#query-execution), but agree that some more advanced query examples like this could be provided within the Craft documentation.

Comment: Yeah I agree, thanks for the reply! I'm always feeling a bit uncomfortable using undocumented code like this since it could change at any moment. Definitely something the documentation could improve on!

Answer (score 0):

You could just do (Assuming your field1 and field2 are set to numbers as Field type):

```
craft.entries.section('mySection').all()
```

as your query then within your loop:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    {% if entry.field1 > entry.field2 %}
        // Show the entry
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It depends on what you need but this would work.

Comment: This seems horrible inefficient, return ALL entries when you only need certain ones. Is there no other way?